# Is it possible for select lists in HTML to have a horizontal scrollbar?

Tags: html, css, select

If you have an HTML `<select multiple>` of a certain width and height (set in CSS), if there are more values then you can possibly fit in that height, then the browser adds a vertical scroll bar. Now if the text is longer than the available width, is it possible to instruct the browser to add a horizontal scrollbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; you'll need to emulate the list yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I'm aware of.

If you'd like, put the list in a div of your desired width, and set the following style on the div:

```
overflow-x: scroll
```

This will cause the div to add a horizontal scroll bar when the select is too wide